# Porting Java SE code to Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, oauth, twitter, blackberry-simulator

I can use this code to connect with twitter and I can get pin when I run this as a java program. I can find the pin, but how do I do this in BlackBerry simulator?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.basic.DefaultOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.signature.SignatureMethod;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        OAuthConsumer consumer = new DefaultOAuthConsumer(
                "my consumerkey",
                "mysecret key here",
                SignatureMethod.HMAC_SHA1);

        OAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(consumer,
                "http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
                "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
                "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

        System.out.println("Fetching request token from Twitter...");

        // we do not support callbacks, thus pass OOB
        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND);

        System.out.println("Request token: " + consumer.getToken());
        System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());

        System.out.println("Now visit:\n" + authUrl
                + "\n... and grant this app authorization");
        System.out.println("Enter the PIN code and hit ENTER when you're done:");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String pin = br.readLine();

        System.out.println("Fetching access token from Twitter...");

        provider.retrieveAccessToken(pin);

        System.out.println("Access token: " + consumer.getToken());
        System.out.println("Token secret: " + consumer.getTokenSecret());

        URL url = new URL("http://twitter.com/statuses/mentions.xml");
        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        consumer.sign(request);

        System.out.println("Sending request to Twitter...");
        request.connect();

        System.out.println("Response: " + request.getResponseCode() + " "
                + request.getResponseMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I dont know how i have to use this code to open the page in simulator. When i was doing it in java i have to copy the link from the console and have to paste the Url which i get on console in a browser and then the browser take me to the requested url and there I give my userid and password and got the pin and pasted it on console and got the access token and Token secret but how to do the similar process in Blackberry Simulator ???? And what changes i have to make in the above code by which it should be open in blackberry simulator i dont know???plz help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to open the Blackberry browser you have to call:

```
Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage("myUrl");
```

Keep in mind that your app must be signed in order to do so. Also, I don't know if those OAuth classes will work in Blackberry.